# Assign place in struct to variable (or pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My struct looks like this:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *children[26];
};

typedef struct Node *List;
```

I would like to assign first (main) struct to variable (or pointer) so I could come back to it (after moving to 'substructs'). i.e

```
start = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
(this variable) = start;
list = (this variable);
list = list -> children[25];
...
list = (this variable) //We're again in main/first struct.
```

Comment: The trouble is that once you've changed `list` to point to the original `list->children[25]`, you've lost your reference to the original.  If you had `temp = list;` and then `temp = list->children[25];` etc, you've kept the original reference around.

Answer (score 1):

so…. why can't you say:

```
List start = malloc(whatever);
List list = start;
list = list->children[25]; // index 26 is out of bounds…
```

Is the problem that you're not sure you can declare something of type List?